# Proper way to redirect to a different page in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

what is the proper way to redirect to a different page in Hybris?I have been the following approach quite a lot:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/path" />">link</a>
```

But some people emphasized that it is better to redirect using a separate method and using redirect:

What is the correct way?

Comment: I have noticed, you have asked many questions on this forum(SO), but you haven't accepted any of the answers.this and this will help you to understand why and how?. spend some time to accept the answers which you got for all your questions. This will help other users and SO community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first tell you basic difference between request **Redirect Vs Forward**.

**Redirect:** Server sends a header (in response) back to the browser/client, which contain redirect URL, then browser initiates a new request to redirect URL.

**When can we use Redirect?**

Usually, when data is posted to the server, we should redirect to get method(URL) to prevent data resubmission on browser refreshed(F5).

```
return "redirect:/redirectToGeturl";
```

---

**Forward:** Within the server, control can be forwarded to target resource(URL). Which is done by container internally so browser/client is not aware of it.

**When can we use forward?**

Sometimes, we want to show different page/resource in response without changing original URL, then we forward request to other controller internally.

```
return "forward:/404";
```

---

> What is the proper way to redirect to a different page in Hybris?

```
public static final String REDIRECT_PREFIX = "redirect:";
public static final String FORWARD_PREFIX = "forward:";
```

This class level constants are defined in AbstractController. You can use that by extending your controller to AbstractPageController or AbstractController.

```
return REDIRECT_PREFIX + "/redirecturl";
return FORWARD_PREFIX + "/404";
```

> < a href="< c:url value="/path" />">link< /a >

This is the correct way to declare a link on client/browser side, which sends GET request to `/path` once the user clicks it.

---

### Find detail [post here](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/how-to-redirect-forward-request-hybris.html)